# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-router@3.0.0

Tags: reactjs

I had an error after installed "react-bootstrap-table".

```
├── react@15.4.1 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-router@3.0.0
```

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-addons-linked-state-mixin": "^15.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.6",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^2.6.0",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.8",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-apply-middleware": "0.0.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
    "react-router-relative-links": "^0.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

Thanks any help.

Comment: Unmet peer dependencies are libraries that the library depends on, but that are not installed by default. It's just telling you you need react-router in order to use this library. It doesn't check whether you already have it or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I had understood. Can you explain more about it.
My project still work fine.
Maybe it didn't  affect to my project.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies This has some solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very helpful. :). I understood it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Install React-Intl using NPM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697658/unable-to-install-react-intl-using-npm)

Comment: ok thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This blog post explains Peer Dependancies well! 
https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

> There's one use case where this falls down, however: plugins. A plugin package is meant to be used with another "host" package, even though it does not always directly use the host package. Most plugins never actually depend on their host package.
>  
> The solution to this was peer dependancy

In your case it seems that you don't actually need to install it since I dug through the `react-bootstrap-table` package's repo and found that `react-router@3.0.0` is mentioned as a dev dependency and used in their example app.

So unless they bundle the example along with the package which is highly unlikely, you can ignore it.